# return first row with non-null value. if null , then return first row appearance python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing the following data. the data is sorted by sessionid, datetime (ASC)

```
 df = df.sort_values(['datetime','session_id'],ascending=True)
```

| session_id | source | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **facebook** | **2021-01-23 11:26:34.166000** |
| 1 | twitter | 2021-01-23 11:26:35.202000 |
| *2* | NULL/NAN | *2021-01-23 11:05:10.001000* |
| **2** | **twitter** | **2021-01-23 11:05:17.289000** |
| **3** | **NULL/NAN** | **2021-01-23 13:12:32.914000** |
| 3 | NULL/NAN | 2021-01-23 13:12:40.883000 |

my desired result should be  ( row from each ++session_id++ with first non-null value in ++source++ column
and if all null, then return first appearance ( case id = 3)
)

| session_id | source | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **facebook** | **2021-01-23 11:26:34.166000** |
| **2** | **twitter** | **2021-01-23 11:05:17.289000** |
| **3** | **NULL/NAN** | **2021-01-23 13:12:32.914000** |

The functions `first_valid_index` and `first` give me somehow the results I want.

The `find_first_value`:

- returns the index of the row containing the first valid index and if None it returns no index, which causes me to lose one session_id of my original table.

| session_id | source | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | facebook | 2021-01-23 11:26:34.166000 |
| 2 | twitter | 2021-01-23 11:05:17.289000 |

```
     x = df.groupby(by="session_id")'om_source'].transform(pd.Series.first_valid_index ) newdf = df[df.index==x]
```

The `first`:

it returns the first non null value ++but for each one of the columns separated++ which is not what I am looking for

| session_id | source | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **facebook** | **2021-01-23 11:26:34.166000** |
| *2* | **twitter** | *2021-01-23 11:05:10.001000* |
| **3** | **NULL/NAN** | **2021-01-23 13:12:32.914000** |

```
  newdf =  df.groupby(by="session_id").first()
```

I tried to do something like this, but this unfortunately did not work.

```
df.groupby(by="session_id")['om_source']
.transform(first if ( pd.Series.first_valid_index is None  ) else pd.Series.first_valid_index)
```

Do you have any suggestions? ( I am new to pandas, I am still trying to understand the 'logic' behind it )

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'helper' column like this and sort then drop_duplicates:

```
df.assign(sorthelp=df['source'] == 'NULL/NAN')\
  .sort_values(['sorthelp','datetime','session_id'])\
  .drop_duplicates('session_id')
```

Output:

```
   session_id    source                    datetime  sorthelp
3           2   twitter  2021-01-23 11:05:17.289000     False
0           1  facebook  2021-01-23 11:26:34.166000     False
4           3  NULL/NAN  2021-01-23 13:12:32.914000      True
```

and you can drop the helper column afterwards

```
print(df.assign(sorthelp=df['source'] == 'NULL/NAN')
        .sort_values(['sorthelp','datetime','session_id'])
        .drop_duplicates('session_id')
        .drop('sorthelp', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   session_id    source                    datetime
3           2   twitter  2021-01-23 11:05:17.289000
0           1  facebook  2021-01-23 11:26:34.166000
4           3  NULL/NAN  2021-01-23 13:12:32.914000
```

Answer (score 0):

If your time is already sorted, you can do:

```
print(
    df.iloc[
        df.groupby("session_id")["source"].apply(
            lambda x: x.first_valid_index()
            if not x.first_valid_index() is None
            else x.index[0]
        )
    ]
)
```

Prints:

```
   session_id    source                    datetime
0           1  facebook  2021-01-23 11:26:34.166000
3           2   twitter  2021-01-23 11:05:17.289000
4           3       NaN  2021-01-23 13:12:32.914000
```

---

Or using `:=` operator (Python 3.8+)

```
print(
    df.iloc[
        df.groupby("session_id")["source"].apply(
            lambda x: fi
            if not (fi := x.first_valid_index()) is None
            else x.index[0]
        )
    ]
)
```